# Under what user does my process run on Oracle Linux?

Tags: oracle, linux

We experience problems with directory access on some Oracle databases running on Linux.

We have two kinds of processes that need to read/write files from a directory: 1 started in a user session, 2 started by Oracle scheduled job.

It seems that on some systems these processes run under different Linux users and that permissions on the Linux file system are only granted to one of them.

Is this assumption correct and what users are these?

Comment: The Oracle installer creates a Linux user named `oracle` which is used to run the database instance.

Comment: This does not explain why different processes run under different users.

Comment: Of course they run under different users. A process started in a "user session" obviously uses _that_ user. A process started by the Oracle scheduler runs under the user that started the Oracle instance - which is (typically) `oracle`

Comment: Maybe I did not explain the problem clearly enough. It's the Linux system that denies access to some of the Oracle processes trying to read/write on a directory on the Linux file system. I can give the Linux user "oracle" access to the Linux directory but not all Oracle processes seem to run under the Linux "oracle" account.
So what other Linux accounts are used for running Oracle processes other than the "oracle" account?

Comment: Is the type of scheduler job -  job_type='EXECUTABLE' ?

Comment: Oracle procedure.

Comment: Have a suggestion from elsewhere that the user initiated processes run under the Linux account that the Oracle Listener runs under.

Comment: this assumption is not correct. Please describe your problem more detailed. For what kind of  session does it work and for what kind of  session doesn't it. What is the error message, how do you access the file system. Add the job_type to the problem description. show the definition of the involved groups and users. Are there any ACLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is such a common problem when the database was installed with user separation (grid + oracle user) and DBAs tend to overlook this.

When you use RAC or even just Oracle Restart (with or without ASM), you need to install Grid Infrastructure. Grid Infrastructure can be installed as a different user (typically grid).

When you have Grid Infrastructure, the proper way to handle listeners is through Grid Infrastructure. If Grid Infrastructure was installed with grid user, then the listener runs as grid user.

In Oracle architecture, by design, remote connections log in through the listener, and the database server process is forked by the listener. On Linux/UNIX platforms, the `oracle` binary is owned by oracle user, and it has the setuid bit enabled. grid and oracle users share a common group, and the `oracle` binary can be executed by the members of this group.

Given the above information, remote connections coming through the listener running as grid user can spawn processes whose UID and EUID is the same as the UID of oracle.

So far this is what usually everyone knows. The difference is however the RUID and the inherited privileges because of it.

On a machine with users as (this is the default configuration taken from an Exadata X5-2 compute node, so this is how Oracle officially deploys its configuration):

```
$ id oracle
uid=1001(oracle) gid=1001(oinstall) groups=1001(oinstall),1004(asmdba),1002(dba),1003(dboper)
$ id grid
uid=1000(grid) gid=1001(oinstall) groups=1001(oinstall),1004(asmdba),1005(asmoper),1006(asmadmin)
```

When you log in locally, all user IDs are 1001 (=oracle):

```
sqlplus user/password

SQL>select spid from v$process where addr = (select paddr from v$session where sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid'));

SPID
------------------------
85510

SQL>!ps -o uid,euid,ruid -p 85510
  UID  EUID  RUID
 1001  1001  1001
```

But when you log in through the listener:

```
sqlplus user/password@orcl

SQL>select spid from v$process where addr = (select paddr from v$session where sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid'));

SPID
------------------------
90372

SQL>!ps -o uid,euid,ruid -p 90372
  UID  EUID  RUID
 1001  1001  1000
```

Notice that the RUID is different, it is the UID of grid user.

For example, this can lead to a situation, where file generation from the database with `UTL_FILE` is successful when executed in a scheduled job, but fails when executed from a remote session.

With the above setup, server processes forked by the listener inherit the privileges of grid user. Scheduled jobs spawned by the database itself inherit the privileges of oracle user. If they do not have the same privileges, they will behave differently.